# Java combine parents of two large inheritance chains

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance

I have two parent classes in a huge project, let's say `ClassA` and `ClassB`.  Each class has many subclasses, which in turn have many subclasses, which in turn have many subclasses, etc.

My task is to "marry" these two "families" so that both inherit from a SINGLE parent.  I need to essentially make `ClassA` and `ClassB` one class (parent) to both of their combined subclasses (children).

`ClassA` and `ClassB` both currently implement `Serializable`.

I am currently trying to make both inheritance chains inherit from `ClassA`, and then copy all functions and data members from `ClassB` into `ClassA`.  This is tedious, and I think a terrible solution.

What would be the CORRECT way to solve this problem?

**EDIT - some clarification**

`ClassA` and `ClassB` essentially do the same thing (many calls to many Stored procs, through a series of many classes and method calls of course).

`ClassA`, however, makes the calls to half of the Stored Procs via a new service based (Jersey) architecture we implemented. I am essentially implementing the new service oriented functionality into "FamilyB" in the same way we it has already been done in "FamilyA".  The problem is that each of these families are huge - many classes and long inheritance chains, making small changes has a butterfly effect on the inheritance chains.

If clarification is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Does it make sense to marry these those families? Do `ClassA` and `ClassB` share lots of code?

Comment: @VivinPaliath They share about half.

Comment: There's no "correct" way; it depends. Not sure how copying a bunch of text is tedious, either.

Comment: If you insert a new superclass ClassC, you can probably use refactoring tools to move stuff up with your IDE until ClassA and ClassB are empty.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm copying each function and data member one by one. I want to do that so I know EXACTLY what needs to be copied and what does not.

Comment: But it's a single refactor operation; even if there were a hundred methods (which probably means your class is broken anyway) it'd still be relatively straight forward even if you weren't moving it using the stock refactoring tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first answer that comes to mind is "In general, no".

In order for this to be reasonable, A and B should be special cases of some other thing -- although that is feasible, it would seem unlikely.

Besides that, I don't see any reason to combine any code (and a lot of reasons not to).  Is there some reason you cannot simply have both of them extend X, and leave all their code where it is?

---

I don't think I have enough information for a clear picture yet, but will go with what I have so far.

If you implement a Class X that both Class A and Class B extend, that changes nothing about any subclasses or any use of either class or any subclass.  That is certainly where I'd start.

```
public Class X implements Serializable {}

public Class A extends X implements Serializable
{
  // retain all current code to start
}

public Class B extends X implements Serializable
{
  // and here be all current code also
}
```

You say you are currently thinking of merging Class B into Class A; this sounds problematic; A and B share 'about half' of their code and both have a large inheritance tree below them - something that instantiates a Class A subclass could have its behavior changed by having A get some new functionality.

So instead I would move things slowly from A to X and from B to X.  I would try to move things only if they had commonality between the A and B trees.

For instance, let's say you have method abc() in A and def() in B with the same functionality.  You could move this functionality to X and call it anything you want - I would probably try to give it the name I thought best described its function, whether that came from A, B, or I made up a new one.  Then abc() and def() could invoke this new function, and the code for these methods could be removed from both of them.

```
public class X implements Serializable
{
  public void abcdef()
  {
    // common functionality, merged from A and B
  }
}

public class A extends X implements Serializable
{
  public function abc() { abcdef(); }
}

public class B extends X implements Serializable
{
  public function edf() { abcdef(); }
}
```

One good thing about proceeding this way is that it is clear at each step what has been done.  You could mark it well with comments and have it reviewed, and/or put it through tests to insure that functionality of both the refactored methods was complete and correct; this could be done after one, two, or more methods were refactored, depending on whether you have good setups for review and/or testing.

The only case where this might break is if, for some reason, you want the callers of methods in the two inheritance trees to change, but I don't have any reason (yet) to think that is necessary.  Hopefully all the methods have at least reasonable names describing what they do and passing the parameters that need passing, and the refactoring at the top only affects the implementations, not the calls.  It looks like a big enough job anyway, I'm hoping you don't have to change the calls as well as the functions.

Comment: "simply have both of them extend X" sounds like it might be what I want to do, can you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm editing the post to answer your question about by I can't leave all the code where it is.

Comment: Thank you.  I asked you to elaborate and you did in a very clear manner.  Your explanations are very helpful.  I am going to proceed down this route.

Comment: Glad it helped; I have also made the edits you suggested, I'm not sure why they were rejected by reviewers.  Seems obvious to me I just failed to use the right keywords in a couple of places...

Comment: Thank you lol.  I was thinking the same thing - I don't know why it was rejected either.  I just wanted to make your answer as complete as possible.

Comment: I thought about it more -- the reason they gave, that it would change the meaning, is quite true, it's just that it would *correct* the answer that was incorrect.  And they had an OP correcting the answer, which in general has to be looked at closely, at least.  Whatever, we got it done.

Answer (score 1):

My instinct is to create a new class that has objects of `ClassA` and `ClassB` as members, then use that as the base class for the things that you essentially want to derive from both `ClassA` and `ClassB`. For example:

```
class ClassAB
{
    private ClassA a;
    private ClassB b;

    public void doSomething()
    {
         a.doSomething();
    }

    public void doSomethingElse()
    {
         b.doSomethingElse();
    }

    ...
}
```

Sure, it's tedious, but it seems a lot easier and a lot less likely to lead to bugs than trying to rework `ClassA` and `ClassB` to make this possible. Does that work in this case?

Comment: I like this at first glance, but what do you mean "Sure, it's tedious".  What exactly is tedious?

Comment: Eclipse can auto-generate delegate methods, so it sould take just a few seconds

Comment: @SoylentGreen Creating the delegated methods, but you should just be able to select all the methods you want to delegate using the stock refactoring tools. When two classes have the same method it gets interesting, basically manual resolution to the diamond problem.

Comment: The problem of the two classes having the same method is one of the benefits of this approach in my opinion, since you can have one function that delegates to each and choose whatever function names you like to differentiate between them.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a new class that `ClassA` and `ClassB` both extend and then start merging shared functionality up there.

Be sure that it actually makes sense to merge the code from `ClassA` and `ClassB` though.

Comment: This is ultimately what I have decided to do, rcook's answer provided more explanation and examples, however.